# How to correct stack location arm-none-eabi-gcc?

Tags: gcc, arm, bare-metal, linker-scripts, cortex-a

I try to create a bare metal code using the standard lib C.

I started with an assembly code

```
.section .isr_vector 
.global _Reset
_Reset:
    B Reset_Handler /* Reset */
    B .             /* Undefined */
    B .             /* SWI */
    B .             /* Prefetch Abort */ 
    B .             /* Data Abort */
    B .             /* reserved */
    B .             /* IRQ */
    B .             /* FIQ */  

.global Reset_Handler
 Reset_Handler:
    ldr sp, =_estack
    mov fp, #0

    // Branch to C code  
    BL _start
    B .
```

I found example of code using symbol `_estack` to locate the stack

In the linker file I put:

```
ENTRY(_Reset)

MEMORY
{
    RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 512M
}
/* define stack size and heap size here */
stack_size = 4*1024;
heap_size = 128*1024; 
/* define beginning and ending of stack */
_estack  = ORIGIN(RAM)+LENGTH(RAM);
_sstack = _estack - stack_size;
```

With GDB I check that _estack is at the right place 0x20000000

When I trace the code and enter the _start function the $sp change to 0x80000

This is done by taking the info from a memory location with no symbol:

```
-exec disas _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x00000084 <+0>: ldr r3, [pc, #84]   ; (0xdc <_start+88>)
   0x00000086 <+2>: cmp r3, #0
   0x00000088 <+4>: it  eq
   0x0000008a <+6>: ldreq   r3, [pc, #76]   ; (0xd8 <_start+84>)
```

Here are my command lines:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -ffreestanding -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -Wall -O0 -g3  -Wextra -std=c99 -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -Iinclude -Llib src/main.c src/start.s -o bin/main   -Xlinker -static -TSECTIONS.ld
arm-none-eabi-nm bin/main > bin/symbols.txt
arm-none-eabi-objdump --disassemble-all bin/main > bin/asm.S
arm-none-eabi-objdump -s  bin/main > bin/MixedCASM.txt
```

Is there a possibility to know the right symbols to locate the stack?

Comment: You don't show what `main()` does.  There are some standard 'C' features that require setup before calling.  I hope you aren't using argc and argv.  For instance, some math operations such as division may call a compiler helper routine.  Generally this is 'libgcc' which can have assumptions; like you need to copy initial '.data' section to memory.

Comment: bare metal and standard C libraries dont go together by definition, most C library calls result in a system call as in operating system which means not bare metal.  So what C library are you using how are you handling the system calls and how are you handling the bootstrap if any required by that specific C library?

Comment: What MCU do you use?

Comment: I'm not presented what main does because the problem is before entering main. The first function generated by the C compiler is _start. It prepares the code before entering the void main(void). The MCU is Cortex-A9.

Comment: @marcoDiroccho That's CPU, not MCU. What microcontroller do you use?

Comment: I just found the solution.  `_start ` is part of  `crt0 `. I just found the source code  `crt0.S ` and I see that the I to overload the `__stack` constant.